# Mongodb ubuntu - config server and shard together

Tags: mongodb, configuration, sharding

I have the following services on a single shard server:

`sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db/ --port 31001
sudo mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb/ --port 21001`

The same server is using for shard and config.
for now I am testing the environment so I am running these rows manually.
I want to run it as a service. I did not event tried it, adding dbpath twice to the config file will not do the work, can you suggest please a config in order to make these lines run as a service?
thanks

Comment: You want to know how to create a config file with those options?

Comment: @joao, yes, but as I am looking at question I see that I am missing an important part. How do I keep the default ubuntu service and run another one for the config service. I mean, mongo is comming with one mongod service, and here I need 2. thanks

Comment: Are you in production or testing once you set these up to run as daemons as opposed to interactive shell processes? Where will you log the server output? Do you have a preferred method to run other services on ubuntu or is this a single purpose VM/appliance situation?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve that is to use cron's `@reboot` feature:

```
> crontab -e -u mongodb
@reboot /usr/bin/mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb/ --port 21001 --logpath /var/log/mongodb/configsvr.log --fork
@reboot /usr/bin/mongod --shardsvr --dbpath /data/db/ --port 31001 --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
```

However, you have to make sure that `/etc/security/limits.conf` holds the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple MongoDB services on the same host, you just need to create separate service definitions and configuration files for each service.

As a starting point I would look at the standard [`mongod.upstart` script in Github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/debian/mongod.upstart) and adapt a version to start your config server.

I would also note that for a production system you should always [deploy three config servers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-config-servers/). If you lose your single config server, you will also lose the metadata for your sharded cluster.